# How to Avoid Escape Characters like &, getting in response from JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

The issue I'm facing is, I'm getting "H & M" to upload from an Excel file, after converting it to the **JSON**, even after stringify it, like this:

```
var postData = JSON.stringify(tempData);
```

but it is not catering `&`, and after passing it to **PHP**, it's making into a form data as you can see in the image below.

Is there any **javascript**  library or any other way around to handle this thing? Please do let me know.

Thank You...!

[image]

Comment: You will need to post an abbreviated version of your conversion code because the problem could be in there

Comment: I'm getting data in tempData variable, after stringify, I'm sending it to PHP to insert into the table.